# How many milliliters in 100 grams?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, ratio, unit-of-measure

Looking at an imaginary ice cream's nutrition facts table, say I see the following information:

- Per Serving Size: 100ml
- Calories Per Serving: 250
- Calories Per 100 Grams: 500

What's the formula to compute the milliliters in 100 grams?

Intuitively, the answer is 200 ml: 100ml = 250 calories, therefore 200ml = 500 calories -- and that's 100 grams). I'm just not sure how to express this in a proper formula.

Comment: You need the concept of [Density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density).

Comment: Then I was way off as I thought this could be solved with basic algebra.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin no, he doesn't

Comment: He does not need to be told the density as it can be calculated but knowing the concept will help a lot.  100g of lead or gold flavoured ice cream will be a lot smaller than hydrogen or helium flavoured ice cream.

Comment: Density doesn't really help here, you're right some algebra helps solving it sometimes at these types of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Let's say that the answer is $x$ milliliters. Then you would have $\frac{x}{100}$ servings from the first bullet point. From that, you can multiply $250$ to find the total amount of calories: $\frac{x}{100}*250=\frac{5x}2$ total calories. Then set up a proportion like this(from third bullet point):$$\frac{500\ \text{Calories}}{100\ \text{grams}}=\frac{5x/2}{100\text{ grams}}$$Which simplifies to $\frac{5x}2=500\implies x=200\ \text{ml}$

I'm not sure if this is the "formulaic" way that you wanted, but it is certainly systematic. This sure overcomplicates the problem though(you can solve this problem in your head without variables).

Comment: The math is correct but the starting data probably not, since this would tell that ice cream has half the density of pure water, while in fact should be slightly heavier for equal volumes (100 grams of water occupy 100 milliliters in the metric system)

Comment: @AndreaMori Imaginary ice cream is available in a wide range of densities.